# Can OpenCV VideoCapture accept a Python file-like object?

Tags: python, opencv

This works fine:

```
import cv2
cv2.VideoCapture('somevideo.mp4').isOpened()

> True
```

This throws an exception:

```
import cv2
f = open('somevideo.mp4', 'rb')
cv2.VideoCapture(f)

> TypeError: an integer is required (got type _io.BufferedReader)
```

I would like the latter example to work because I have a Python file-like object that abstracts the location of the file (not a standard OS filesystem).

Can OpenCV be coaxed into accepting a standard python file-like object? From this exception it looks like it will only support a file descriptor or filename string.

Comment: It doesn't even support a file descriptor.

Comment: pyav, which is a python library for ffmpeg, can do this for you. Have a look at https://pyav.org/docs/develop/api/_globals.html?highlight=av%20open#av.open.

Comment: @samlaf That would make a good additional answer to post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV is a C++ library with Python bindings auto-generated. Partly because of that, in general, the Python library is not really extensible or flexible at all. The parameter you send into the function gets sent to C++, and you will get an error on anything it's not expecting. From [the latest docs](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html), the available constructors for a `VideoCapture` object are:

```
VideoCapture ()
Default constructor. More...

VideoCapture (const String &filename, int apiPreference=CAP_ANY)
Opens a video file or a capturing device or an IP video stream for video capturing with API Preference. More...

VideoCapture (int index, int apiPreference=CAP_ANY)
Opens a camera for video capturing. More...
```

So you can see the only valid signatures contain either an integer index for the device number, or a string which is expected to be a filename. The `open()` method has the same expectations on signatures.

OpenCV doesn't really provide first class support for video; instead it relies on a number of possible backend libraries. Your best bet if you want swap-ability is just to copy the API and use some other library (perhaps `ffmpeg`) to decode the raw binary stream.

Another idea would be to create a webserver and serve the data. OpenCV accepts URLs in addition to filenames. This introduces latency though, even when serving locally, so it's not a great option (but if the video is remote anyways, then maybe it's not a bad idea).

Comment: What I don't understand though, is that pyav is also just pythong bindings for ffmpeg (opencv uses ffmpeg as a backend), yet it can accept a file-like object (see the link in my answer to op's question).

Comment: @samlaf Sure, it's a different library. There isn't anything technical preventing OpenCV from doing it, they'll eventually just open the file and read it anyways. But they don't let you provide a file stream, only a file path.